# event.stopPropagation(); to hide dropdown, but not when it is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I want to get the button `.notification` to make `.notificaiton-dropdown` appear, and clicking outside of this element would close it. This works.

However, when I go to click on the element, it causes it to close. I want the current functionality, but not when clicking on the element itself so I can interact with it.

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $('.notification').click( function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
        $('.notification-dropdown').toggle();
    });
    $(document).click( function(){
        $('.notification-dropdown').hide();
    });
});
```

I hope that's enough information. Thanks as always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to stop the event propagation from `notification-dropdown` also

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $('.notification-dropdown').click( function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
    $('.notification').click( function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
        $('.notification-dropdown').toggle();
    });
    $(document).click( function(){
        $('.notification-dropdown').hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd say:

```
$(document).click( function(e){
    if($(e.target).closest('.notification-dropdown').length) return;
    $('.notification-dropdown').hide();
});
```